# Finding Temporary windows 10 files

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files

When I look in windows 10 at the Storage usage it says I have 8GB+ of temporary files.[image]

When I select the Temporary Files link it takes me to a list that looks very like the disk cleanup options and only comes to 30Mb.  where is the other 8Gb...

I have looked in all of the locations I can think of and looked at previous super user questions/answers.  I understand that windows 10 has multiple temp locations but I thought I had looked at them all.

What I have tried

- C:/Windows/temp
- Appdata/local/TEMP
- Disk cleanup is fully cleaned (including system files)

The total appData folder is now only 400Mb so I know its not hiding in there.

I know they are in the C://Windows folder (as its size is roughly the size of the systems + temp categories).

Can anyone help with finding these temp files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the source.  It was from a previous Windows update that failed to clean up or come up in the Disk System cleanup checks.

There were exactly 8.35GB of Downloads in the Software updates folder of 
C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download

Why they didn't come up int the Disk system cleanup I don't know, but I believe from some research that they can be safely deleted (manually).

I deleted them and the Temporary files category decreased by 8.35Gb.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Actually those are temporary files, they just failed to get cleaned up automatically. DIsk cleanup does not check the software distribution folder.